# WPF, How Prism link Views and URI

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm learning Prism and I don't understand how the navigation is done with the URI. In this [documentation example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430881(v=pandp.40).aspx), the [code on github](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/View-Switching%20Navigation_Desktop_Unity) use:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, calendarViewUri);
}
```

The URI is declared like this:

```
private static Uri calendarViewUri = new Uri("CalendarView", UriKind.Relative);
```

There is a CalendarView.xaml declared, in the code, but how the link is done?
Is Prism just look at the URI and try to find a matching view name then load it into the region?

If my assumption is correct, there is no need to register the link between the URI and the View. But what if a view is renamed, that means the navigation will be broken, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "missing link", look at `ViewSwitchingNavigation.Calendar/CalendarModule.cs`, this is where the calendar module is initialized, i.e. where it makes all its stuff known to the rest of the application:

```
this.unityContainer.RegisterTypeForNavigation<CalendarView>();
```

This basically says "*when asked to navigate to* 'CalendarView'*, create an instance of* `CalendarView`".